# i18n Not allowed nest placeholder

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-i18n

I want to try Interpolation with Vue3 + vue-i18n 9.3. When I try to pass argument I'm getting;

```
Message compilation error: Not allowed nest placeholder
1  |  Showing {{from}} to {{to}} of {{total}} entries
```

My locale json file;

```
...
"showing_0_to_0_of_0_entries": "Showing {{from}} to {{to}} of {{total}} entries",
...
```

Inside my component;

```
<div class="info">{{ $t('showing_0_to_0_of_0_entries',{ from: 0, to: 15, total:8 }) }}</div>
```

But It's not working, I'm getting error and in my page displaying text like that;

```
Showing {{from}} to {{to}} of {{total}} entries
```

Not veriables passing. What ı can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to documentation I should use one curly brackets like `{}`. So here is my solution;

```
"showing_0_to_0_of_0_entries": "Showing {from} to {to} of {total} entries",
```

[Documentation](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/essentials/syntax.html)